# MySQL Group by one column if another has changed?

Tags: mysql

I've been looking to see if there's a MySQL selector that would allow me to select by one column if another has a different value.

Example:

```
id name  value
----------------
1  john   1
2  craig  1
3  john   2
```

So, what I'd be looking to do is select both rows 1 and 3 since they have the same `name` and the `value` has changed.

If this isn't possible, I can parse through all the results in code, but if MySQL can do this for me, even better!

Comment: Is it possible your table has one more rows : `4, craig, 1` ? i mean _two rows with same values_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from `table` where Name in (
select name from `table` Group by Name having Count(*)>1)
```

Inner select Looks for names that exists more than one in your table and the outer select get the data for that name.

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the names that have more than value, and then all the rows with those names:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  name IN (SELECT   name
                FROM     mytable
                GROUP BY name
                HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work;

```
select * from table a
where exists 
(select b.id from table b
where a.name = b.name and a.value <> b. value)
```